# how to solve python path error: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python

I want to run my python code using this command:

```
python3.8 __main__.py
```

but shows this error:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/musicbox/NEMbox% python3.8 __main__.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import __version__
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

this is the `__main__.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import _curses
import argparse
import curses
import sys
import traceback

from . import __version__
from .menu import Menu


def start():
    version = __version__

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "-v", "--version", help="show this version and exit", action="store_true"
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.version:
        latest = Menu().check_version()
        try:
            curses.endwin()
        except _curses.error:
            pass
        print("NetEase-MusicBox installed version:" + version)
        if latest != version:
            print("NetEase-MusicBox latest version:" + str(latest))
        sys.exit()

    nembox_menu = Menu()
    try:
        nembox_menu.start_fork(version)
    except (OSError, TypeError, ValueError, KeyError, IndexError):
        # clean up terminal while failed
        try:
            curses.echo()
            curses.nocbreak()
            curses.endwin()
        except _curses.error:
            pass
        traceback.print_exc()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

and this is the `__init__.py` file in the same level of `__main__.py`:

```
from importlib_metadata import version

from .const import Constant
from .utils import create_dir
from .utils import create_file

__version__ = version("NetEase-MusicBox")


def create_config():
    create_dir(Constant.conf_dir)
    create_dir(Constant.download_dir)
    create_file(Constant.storage_path)
    create_file(Constant.log_path, default="")
    create_file(Constant.cookie_path, default="#LWP-Cookies-2.0\n")


create_config()
```

why would this happen and what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you directly execute a script with `python <script name>`, that script is the `__main__` module. It is not part of a package. Relative imports only work from inside a package, since python needs to have a parent package to import relative to.

Considering you have a `__init__.py` and a `__main__.py` file inside a `NEMbox` folder, I assume you can get it to do the correct think by executing (from the folder which contains `NEMbox`, e.g. `musicbox`) `python3 -m NEMbox`. That will execute the module `NEMbox`. When `NEMbox` is a package and not a directly a file `NEMbox.__main__` will get execute (which is what you want here).

(Note: I can't read the language, but the [original github page](https://github.com/darknessomi/musicbox) seems to have precise install instructions.